# How to identify an index with last letter y?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need to make a method to return an array containing all strings that are at least 6 characters long and also end with y. Ending with y is stumping me. I'm not sure how to do that.

I have tried using:

```
if words.length >= 6 && words[-1] == "y"
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. 
It just returns with a blank. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: " It just returns with a blank." can you show the full method and how you're calling it?

Comment: I assume that `words` (plural) is your array of strings? If so, your code checks whether the array contains at least 6 elements and if the last element is the string `"y"`. That's probably not what you want. Try `words.select { |string| string.length >= 6 && string[-1] == "y" }` instead to [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-select) _elements_ satisfying your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

```
a=["abcdey",'mckejy','jay','jjjjjjy','aaaaaa']
```

Code

```
p a.filter{|x|x.length.eql?6 and x[-1].downcase.eql?'y'}
```

or

```
p a.select{|x|x.length.eql?6 and x[-1].downcase.eql?'y'}
```

Output

```
["abcdey", "mckejy"]
```

If you want to create a method then

```
def findTheString a
  a.filter {|x| x.length.eql? 6 and x[-1].downcase.eql? 'y'}
end

a=["abcdey", 'mckejy', 'jay', 'jjjjjjy', 'aaaaaa']

p findTheString a
```

As Cary suggested, Here is the regular expression solution

```
p a.filter{|x|x[/\A.{5}(y|Y)\z/]}
```

Comment: As an alternative, consider using a regular expression (with anchors).

Comment: It would be great if you write an answer. I am not good in regular expression.

Comment: There's no time like the present to practice. You want to match the beginning of the string followed by at least 5 characters (any characters) followed by a `'y'` followed by the end of the string, case-indifferent. Bye.

Comment: There is also `x.end_with?("y", "Y')` if you want to avoid regexps.

Comment: @steenslag yes, I have forgotten that function but anyway I am not using regex.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Added.

Comment: Refusing regexps when programming Ruby is like refusing a spoon when eating soup.

Comment: @user1934428 i am not refusing.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Cary Swoveland, here is a solution using Regexp, including a Benchmark:

```
require "benchmark/ips"

RE_1 = /\A.{5,}y\z/i
RE_2 = /.{5}y\z/i
INPUT = ["abcdey", 'mckejy', 'jay', 'jjjjjjy', 'aaaaaa', 'aaaaaY', 'aaaaaaaY'].freeze

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.compare!
  x.report("select (downcase)") do
    INPUT.select{ |word| word.length >= 6 && word[-1].downcase == 'y' }
  end

  x.report("select (or)") do
    INPUT.select{ |word| word.length >= 6 && (word[-1] == 'y' || word[-1] == 'Y') }
  end

  x.report("re 1") do
    INPUT.select { |word| RE_1.match?(word) }
  end

  x.report("re 2") do
    INPUT.select { |word| RE_2.match?(word) }
  end
end


Comparison:
                re 2:   633881.7 i/s
                re 1:   615253.4 i/s - same-ish: difference falls within error
   select (downcase):   499513.6 i/s - 1.27x  slower
         select (or):   405617.5 i/s - 1.56x  slower
```

Comment: I believe that should be `/\A.{5,}(y|Y)\z/`, `/.{5}(y|Y)\z/`, or (best, imo) `INPUT.grep(/.{5}y\z/i)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland obviously you are right.

The OP asked for 6 or more characters long, not just six. Updated.

Comment: Also added the Regexp suggested by Carry. It seems a tad faster. But fo course these Microbenchmarks should be taken with a grain of salt.